# Exponential growth of the Irish population in 20 years

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

### Background

> In 1992, there were approximately $3.514$M people living in Ireland. Today, in 2022, there are approximately $5.08$M people. Assuming the growth continues like that, how many people will there be 20 years from now?

I've created the above question, for practice, and I've changed the figures from [example 2](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/exponential-growth.html) via mathisfun.

### My Attempt

Starting with the exponential growth formula

$$y(t) = a\times e^{kt}$$

we know $a=3514000$ people, $t=30$ years, and right now $y(30)=5080000$ people. Therefore,

$$\begin{align*}
5080000&=3514000e^{30k}\\
\frac{3514000e^{30k}}{35140000}&=\frac{5080000}{3514000}&&\text{Swap and divide both sides by 3514000}\\
\ln(e^{30k})&=\ln\left(\frac{2540}{1757}\right)&&\text{Take the natural logarithm of both sides}\\
30k&=\ln\left(\frac{2540}{1757}\right)&&\ln(e^{x})=x\\
k&=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2540}{1757}\right)}{30}&&\text{Solve for k}\\
&\approx0.01228\\
\end{align*}$$
Now, we put $k$ back into our formula
$$\begin{align*}
y(50)&=3514000e^{(50\times0.01228)}\\
&\approx6493196.846\\
\end{align*}$$

Would this process be correct? 
Also, would it be preferable to include $k=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2540}{1757}\right)}{30}$ into the final derivation for $y(50)$, or would the approximation $k\approx0.01228$ suffice?

Comment: Your answer is excessively precise (fractions of a person when the input data is in thousands or ten-thousands).  Your premature rounding would also introduce errors at that precision and if you used $k=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2540}{1757}\right)}{30}$ you would get about $6.495$ million ($6494888.24$ rounded).  You can also get this result as $5.08 \times \left(\frac{5.08}{3.514}\right)^{(20/30)}$

Comment: That works, and 4 digits of precision on $k$ will be enough for this approximation problem that only gave 4 digits of precision to begin with. Another way to approach this is to note that $y(20)/y(0) = [y(0)/y(-30)]^{2/3}$.